# Merge two objects in one model class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, webclient

I have received this json message from a queue in rabbitmq:

```
{
    "type": "NEW",
    "operation": "NEW",
    "id": 1,
    "entity": "DOCUMENT",
    "entityType": "NIE",
    "documents": {
        "id": 1,
        "additionals": {
            "issuing_authority": "Spain",
            "country_doc": "ES",
            "place_of_birth": "",
            "valid_from": "1995-08-09",
            "valid_to": "0001-01-01"
        },
        "code": "X12345",
        "typeDocument": "NIE"
    }
}
```

Then I need to map to this model class:

```
public class PeopleDocumentDTO {

    private String processType;
    private String operation;
    private String entity;
    private String entityType;
    private Long id;
    private Document document;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Customer {
        private String systemId;
        private String customerId;
    }
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

To do this I have done this in my @RabbitListener class:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${event.queue}")
    public void receivedMessage(Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {

        String json = "";

        json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(json);

        logger.info("Received message: {}", json);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PeopleDocumentDTO dto = objectMapper.readValue(json, PeopleDocumentDTO.class);}
```

On the other hand, I have this service class who is giving me the customer object in the Customer class that need to be added to my model class giving an specific id, as follows:

```
public Mono<Person> getPerson(Integer id, String GS_AUTH_TOKEN) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

        return webClient.get()
                .uri(GET_RELATION_BY_ID + id)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", GS_AUTH_TOKEN)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Person.class)
                .map(person -> {
                    List<CustomerRelation> matches = person.getRelatedCustomers()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(relation -> relation.getSystemId().equals(400) || relation.getSystemId().equals(300) || relation.getSystemId().equals(410))
                            .filter(relation -> relation.getCustomerId().contains("F"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    person.setRelatedCustomers(matches);
                    return person;
                });
    }
```

So at the end my question is how can I add this object to my model class? So I can have something like this in postman:

```
{
    "type": "NEW",
    "operation": "NEW",
    "id": 1,
    "entity": "DOCUMENT",
    "entityType": "NIE",
    "documents": {
        "id": 1,
        "additionals": {
            "issuing_authority": "Spain",
            "country_doc": "ES",
            "place_of_birth": "",
            "valid_from": "1995-08-09",
            "valid_to": "0001-01-01"
        },
        "code": "X12345",
        "typeDocument": "NIE"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "relatedCustomers": [
        {
            "customerId": "xxx",
            "systemId": 999
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The RestController to get the related customers is as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/getId/{Id}")
    public Mono<CuCoPerson> getRelationById(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String GS_AUTH_TOKEN) {

        return webClientService.getCuCoPerson(id, GS_AUTH_TOKEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to Person object and `getRelatedCustomers()` and do `dto.setCustomers()`

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "${event.queue}")
public void receivedMessage(Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {

        String json = "";

        json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(json);

        logger.info("Received message: {}", json);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PeopleDocumentDTO dto = objectMapper.readValue(json, PeopleDocumentDTO.class);
        
        personServie.getPerson("id", "authToken").subscribe(person -> dto.setCustomers(person.getRelatedCustomers()));
        
}
```

You can change `customers` to `relatedCustomers` in `PeopleDocumentDTO` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! And where should I get the id and authToken from? Should I passed those like this: public void receivedMessage(Message message, Integer id, String authToken)

Comment: That's up to implementation of your application. I don't know from where you will get it. It won't come to receive message method. Check with your team members.

Comment: I am getting the token and the id in the controller coming from the microservice that I am calling.